# Why does python print '\n' instead of moving on to the next line?

Tags: python, recursion

I am a complete newbie to programming.
Currently, I am working on a simple code to print a triangle with stars.

```
def star_drawer(n):
    if n==1:
        return('*')
    elif n>1:
        return str(star_drawer(n-1))+'\n'+"*"*n
```

if i run the code, `n=3` for example, the shell displays `'*\n**\n***'`
in stead of

```
*
**
***
```

I do not understand why \n does not work.

Comment: How are you printing the value?

Comment: Running that code just defines a function.

Comment: `print star_triangle(3)` would print value. Simple call in interactive interpreter shows `repr()` of string.

Comment: This code is not complete. What is `star_drawer`? And after `def` should come an intended block.

Comment: Your code works for me after I fix the indentation and use `star_triangle()` instead of `star_drawer()`.

Comment: @moose I think you intended indented.

Comment: >>> star_drawer(4)
'*\n**\n***\n****'
>>>  #this is how it's displayed

Comment: Read @Rogalski's comment. Try `print star_drawer(4)` in you console.

Comment: Or `print(star_drawer(4))` if you're using Python 3.x(also works in Python 2.x).

Comment: it works when I use print(star_drawer(n)) but I want to know the difference between printing it and simply using star_drawer(n)

By the way, this is my first question on stackoverflow, and the answers are so helpful- much appreciated.

Comment: return gives back the value as it. print formats the output of the value depending on the value and selected formating

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Python may have two string *representations*. `str(obj)` is the way you would print it, and `repr(obj)` is a way to understand how it is. When you only type the name of an object in the interactive console, it is the same as printing its `repr`.

Example:

```
>>> a = 'a\nb'
>>> a
'a\nb'
>>> repr(a)
"'a\\nb'"
>>> print repr(a)
'a\nb'
>>> print a
a
b
```

So you need to use `print` (in Python 2.7) or `print(...)` (in Python 3) to actually display the strings instead of showing their repr value.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done more efficiently without recursion as

```
def star(n):
    return "\n".join("*" * i for i in range(1, n+1))
```